# Activiti 5 default username/password

Tags: activiti

I  have just installed Activiti 5, and tried the passwords posted in the online documentation, but they don't work.

Does anyone know what is the default password in Activiti 5, or where is it published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs it: kermit/kermit

Answer (score 3):

The username and password is included in documentation. For version 6 it's admin/test. The document is [here](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/6.latest/index.html#_getting_started_10_minute_tutorial).